# why data visit becomes quicker after hash

Tags: hash

Why does hash make data visit (key, value) quicker than original pair?

In other words, why do we need hash function h() after all? the range of h() seems still just another integer.

Comment: What do you mean by "quicker than original pair"? Like just putting the value in an array, having the key be the index?

Comment: @ConnorRobetorye, yes, why bother to hash keys to another number after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that visiting/accessing data stored in a hash table is no faster than visiting that same data stored in an array (given that you already know the index/key the value is stored at in the array). In fact, it is marginally slower to access the data in a hash table, since with an array you're just using an index as a key to access the data, whereas for a hashed key/value pair you have to compute the key's index in the hash table with h() before you can access it.

However, hash tables aren't used primarily for their fast *access* to data values given their keys (although they're still very fast in this regard): they are used for fast *searching* for data values given keys: fast access that persists even when the keys/values being stored are dynamically changing. Additionally, a hash table lets you use arbitrary types of values as keys whereas arrays restrict you to integer (index) keys. And even if you only need integer keys, hash tables are generally much more space efficient for storing key/value pairs than arrays.

So, for example, if you already know that a desired value is stored at index `n` in an array `A` and that it will always be at index `n`, or you just want to access whatever value is at index `n` regardless of what it is, then great---just use an array and call `A[n]` every time you want that value.

Where hashing comes in is when you *don't know* whether some key/value is stored, or you know the value is stored but you aren't tracking exactly where. A hash lets you compute an index for the key you're looking for and check that index to retrieve the value in constant time, but with an un-hashed array you would have to do a full linear search to try and find a value if you aren't explicitly tracking its index.

This is because a vanilla array just isn't very suited to storing key/value pairs for quick lookup. The keys you can use for lookup are limited to the indexes of the array (or some integer mapping from differently typed keys to integers, which is basically already a hash function), and, generally speaking, when you're storing some collection of values in a dynamically changing array, you aren't going to know the exact index where each value is being stored at, meaning doing a fast (constant time) lookup of values based on keys won't be possible without maintaining a separate mapping from keys to array indexes which itself would be costlier than biting the bullet and doing a linear search on every lookup.

Even if the set of keys you want to store values for isn't changing and all keys are integers, meaning you could theoretically store keys/values in a simple array by just storing key 1 at index 1, key 2 at index 2,... and you therefore wouldn't need a hash function or a separate mapping from keys to array indexes for lookup in a dynamically changing set of key/value pairs to be efficient: even if that all were true, using an array to implement key/value lookup directly based on index rather than a hashed index is still likely going to waste a ton of space. This is because a simple array-based key/value lookup needs space for each potential key it could store. Because every key gets its own index, an array without a hash needs space proportional to the *range of keys* it's storing. However, a hash function collapses the range of keys down to the size of the underlying hash table, which itself will be a constant multiple of the *number* of keys currently being stored. This means hashing approach will generally be much more efficient because there's little wasted space, potentially orders of magnitude less wasted space compared to storing a sparse but wide range of un-hashed keys.

So basically, if you want fast data retrieval of values by keys, it's not going to be time or space efficient to just use integer keys directly as you might through array indexes -- Aside from very specialized cases, fast retrieval by key will require an auxiliary data structure like a hash table + hash function or a tree.